# VBA - Checking date string validity

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a string in the following format in Excel.

```
07/12/2015 08:00 - 08/12/2015 09:00
```

I want to check if the current date fits between the two (these dates are validity dates, meaning I have to check if the current date is bigger than the first date and smaller than the second date).

I sometimes also have this string without hours, so like:

```
07/12/2015 - 08/12/2015
```

so I have to check that as well (just without the hours).

---

I split the dates using the Split function to split by the "-" character. However, I'm not sure how to do the check because I've never worked with dates.

Can anyone show me how to do this? It seems that it'd be complicated with the check for the hours.

Comment: @Synoon, he needs to parse the date, not to format it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Dim mydate as String, splitdate as Variant
mydate = "07/12/2015 08:00 - 08/12/2015 09:00"

splitdate = Split(mydate, "-")
If Date < splitdate(0) And Date > splitdate(1) Then MsgBox "Is Between"
```

In case there will be some issues with understanding date formats, you can still use Cdate function -

```
If Date < CDate(splitdate(0)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that you String is located in A1, and the Date you want to check for is in B1, then put this formula in C1:

```
=IF(AND(B1>=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10)),B1<=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+2,10))),TRUE,FALSE)
```

This works for both cases, if you are only interested if the date lies between the dates (thus excluding the time).

Answer (score 0):

Use cdate function. You wrote you already used the split function, so all you need to do is put the separate date strings into date variables using cdate ('c' stands for cast). 
So

```
Dim d1 as Date
Dim d2 as Date

d1 = CDate(splitstring(0))
d2 = CDate(splitstring(1))
```

Then you can check the given date.

Answer (score 0):

With the `CDate()` conversion function and `Trim` (to get rid of useless spaces), here is a boolean function that you can easily use to test if you are in the time lapse described by your string.

Here is how to use it :

```
Sub test_Gilbert_Williams()
Dim TpStr As String
TpStr = "08/12/2015 08:00 - 08/12/2015 09:00"
'TpStr = "07/12/2015 - 08/12/2015"

MsgBox Test_Now_Date_Validity(TpStr)
End Sub
```

And the function :

```
Public Function Test_Now_Date_Validity(Date_Lapse As String) As Boolean
Dim A() As String, _
    Date1 As Date, _
    Date2 As Date

If InStr(1, Date_Lapse, "-") Then
    A = Split(Date_Lapse, "-")
    Debug.Print Trim(A(0)) & " " & CDate(Trim(A(0)))
    Debug.Print Trim(A(1)) & " " & CDate(Trim(A(1)))
    If CDate(A(0)) > CDate(A(1)) Then
        Date1 = CDate(A(1))
        Date2 = CDate(A(0))
    Else
        Date1 = CDate(A(0))
        Date2 = CDate(A(1))
    End If
    If Now > Date1 And Now < Date2 Then
        Test_Now_Date_Validity = True
    Else
        Test_Now_Date_Validity = False
    End If
Else
    Exit Function
End If
End Function
```